# Preventing a feature from being upgraded

Tags: installation, installshield

I have a tool which automatically creates InstallShield installers (InstallScript, not MSI), and my main problem at the moment is that when upgrading an installation, I need a way to prevent features from being **upgraded**. During the installation, I want to check the version of a exe-file installed on the target system, and depending on this I want to be able to exclude a specific feature from the set of files being upgraded.

I tried to implement this by calling `FeatureSelectItem(feature, FALSE)` in the feature's `OnInstalling` event handler, but this causes the entire feature to be **uninstalled**, which is not what I want. I just want the feature to be excluded from the upgrade.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Acresso's support team, this is not possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

If there are parts of your installation that are versioned/maintained independently, you may want to create separate installations for them. Then you could use your InstallScript as a bootstrapper to upgrade each installation separately based on your conditions.

Comment: This is not an option, I'm afraid. InstallShield installers are far to heavyweight for this to be practical.